# How do I move lines in a ggplot to create a 3D effect and add a pseudo-axis that indicates the name of each line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, line

I have 3 lines in a plot which I want to move 1 unit on the X axis and 100 units on the Y axis to create a 3D effect as in the example below. So far I have only been able to do the lines. I tried with the `position_nudge()` function, but it didn't have the effect I expected, it changed the scale of the axes, but not the position of the lines.

Plus: If the plot with the frames looks like a cube, that would be a great thing.

Example:

[image]

MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)

Group <- c("A", "B", "C")
Time <- 0:10
DF <- expand.grid(Time = Time,
                  Group = Group)

DF$Y <- c(rep(1,5), 100, rep(1,5),
          rep(1,5), 500, rep(1,5),
          rep(1,5), 1000, rep(1,5))

ggplot(data = DF,
       aes(x = Time,
           y = Y,
           color = Group)) +
  geom_line(position = position_nudge(y = 100, x=1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: See [`ggridges`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html)

Comment: I'd think first about whether that's actually the best and most representative way to display your data. Having a 3D effect like this means the curves no longer all have the same y-axis—the ones further back are set higher, implying higher values along the y-axis. The workaround for that would be a y-axis for each curve and moving those axes into 3D also, which will become hard to read. I'd second @Henrik's suggestion of a ridgeplot instead